# popup shows and disappears when OnClientClick="ShowPopup()

Tags: asp.net

when showpopup return it doesn't disappear but no value if there is no return it showed and disappeared but one I click on it again it showed value but soon it disappear

```
<ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Button ID="btndetails" runat="server"
                        CommandName="ShowPopup" OnClientClick="ShowPopup();return false  ;"

                        Text="select issue"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
```

code behind

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender,GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ShowPopup")
    {

        Button btndetails = (Button)e.CommandSource;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
       // lblID.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
      // lblID.Text = GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        lblID.Text = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
       // lblContactName.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
        //txtAddress.Text = gvrow.Cells[5].Text;
       // txtCity.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[4].Text);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OnClientClick` attribute renders a javascript `onclick` handler into the HTML of the control. To see what this means, try the following:

```
OnClientClick="alert('this is a javascript method, and will not execute in C#')"
```

The language of the rest of your question is rather confusing. Would you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish?